# Make a JSON Object out of a TextView

Tags: android, json, qr-code, jsonobjectrequest

I am trying to scan a QR code which gives me my data in a textview. How can I take this data and make it into a JSON object? Is it even possible? I am trying to take a textview with multiple data points and make it into a JSON object so I can post it using postman.

This is the data coming through the QR code into the textview.

```
 [
      {"Sensor Type": "Environment",
    "Sensor ID":"5a7de613e13508be088dc4a8",
    "Vendor Name":"Monnit",
    "Vendor ID": "5a7ddc2de13508be088dc4a7",
    "Project Location Name": "862 White Street, Dubuque, IA, 52001",
    "Project Location ID": "5a01c555ad63f900b5411eed",
    "Gateway Name": "Gateway Test - Planning Stage",
    "Gateway ID":"5b1836f3389a4eaa38ff887f",
    "Vendor Sensor Type": "Temperature Test - Planning Stage",
    "Vendor Sensor ID": "NotAssignedYet"}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to that use a library called Gson

https://github.com/google/gson

Create a java class consisting of all the attributes like sensorType, sensorId etc. as required. Also create an constructor, getters & setters. Create its object as done:- (Let name of model or Pojo is Vendor.java

```
Vendor vendor = new Vendor();
```

Set Data in it. This can either be set using getters and setters or directly:-

```
vendor.sensorType = "Environment";
vendor.sensorId = "5a7de613e13508be088dc4a8";
```

and so on...

Now, use Gson to convert that object into Json.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(vendor);
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers - do read @Opriday

Comment: There is a very useful library `Gson` where you can parse string to json, json to model, model to json string.

Comment: How is this getting the data out of the textview?

Comment: What data are you getting in textview?? Plz attach that too @RoniSkinner. Then its depend on that whether it contains arrays, objects or not.

Comment: @Raj Added it to my original question.

Comment: I have updated my answer @RoniSkinner. As its a long string so using a Gson library would be a better approach to do this job.

Comment: I have added the Gson library but it doesn't recognize Vendor. Where do you init this? @Raj